# Failed to submit JobGraph Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run the simple code below after building everything from Flink's github master branch for various reasons. I get an exception below and I wonder what runs on port 9065? and How to fix this exception?

```
 val dataStream = senv.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 4)
 dataStream.countWindowAll(2).sum(0).print()
 senv.execute("My streaming program")
```

Below is the Exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
  at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$18(RestClusterClient.java:306)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
  at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$222(RestClient.java:196)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:268)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:284)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:9065
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:943)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
  ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:9065
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
```

I build it from the sources in the following way (just followed the instructions on Flink github page):

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/flink.git
cd flink
mvn clean package -DskipTests 
cd build-target
./bin/start-scala-shell.sh local
```

Comment: How do you run this stuff? Embedded? Local flink cluster?

Comment: Hi! I edited my question and listed all the steps for the question you were asking!

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this error in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underlying distributed runtime is currently heavily worked on in master. Starting from 1.5 the default runtime will be the one known as [FLIP6](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65147077), therefore ocassionally some parts might not work. I think it would be very beneficial if you could create a JIRA ticket for this.

Just to add what runs on 9065 port, in the new architecture it is the default port of Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception. My issue was that I had a port conflict when started the cluster with a docker image on my machine. So I had changed the port for rest in flink config file to use 8084 instead of 8081. When I did this the cluster would start up properly but I was unable to submit the job. When I killed the conflicting process and reverted the port back to 8081, I could submit jobs successfully

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
Use jdk 1.8 for flink 1.7.2